# What do you do with questions that point at a toolchain bug or other such "unlikely" issue?

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-close

Sometimes, usually off in C++ land in my limited experience, us SO denizens get asked seemingly innocuous questions ("why doesn't my code compile? this other compiler accepts it just fine..." is the usual form they take) that actually reveal a compiler *bug*!  Sometimes these questions wind up hanging around for quite a while, sometimes with a few comments of the "file a bug" "oh, I filed a bug, go look at ..." form, but often (?) going unanswered.  Is it good form to answer these more definitively with results from multiple implementations (with the aid of tools like [Godbolt](http://gcc.godbolt.org)) and/or a Standard citation?  Or should these be VTCed after the bug is filed as "not reproducible enough" or "too localized/not helpful to future users", because we're not a bugtracker?

Example questions of this archetype can be found at

[Is it legal to have a function pointer template parameter accept an rvalue reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26631872/is-it-legal-to-have-a-function-pointer-template-parameter-accept-an-rvalue-refer/26639562#26639562)

[virtual inheritance with covariant return type and a template class argument, LINK error in vs2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26042254/virtual-inheritance-with-covariant-return-type-and-a-template-class-argument-li/26655700#26655700)

and

[C++ preprocessor removes whitespace in calls to variadic macros (Solaris Studio 12.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26219063/c-preprocessor-removes-whitespace-in-calls-to-variadic-macros-solaris-studio/26724701#26724701)

Comment: C++ compilers have a lot of bugs.  I don't see anything wrong with those questions, nothing "unlikely" about them.  Knowing that the bug exists is valuable, getting them fixed takes too long.

Comment: Nor do I -- I think they're a good thing to have on SO, but they seem to attract almost no attention all the same -- I'm wondering if there are a large lot of SO users who believe "oh, why the heck would he think it's a compiler bug? It *has* to be his code that's wrong..." and thus don't want to touch questions of the ilk I mentioned.

Comment: These questions have lots of views.  In general, SO users like happy answers, nothing very happy about "yes, it is a bug".

Comment: A-ha -- my instincts in cleaning up the comment-work into more definitive answers were correct, then.  Thanks!

Comment: Most of those questions can be well-answered, by a) proving it is actually a bug (in docs/standard/compiler/library/whatever) and what should happen b) providing a work-around and c) linking the bug-report (if neccessary after filing it). Though if it is already filed and accepted, proving it is a bug might no longer be neccessary, only describing what should have happened according to a strict reading of the contract.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen Java answers  (and written one myself) that linked to the web page for a known bug. An answer which in effect says "you must avoid thus feature or upgrade to version X" is a useful answer.